# ANOVAs with dichotomous and multicategorical IVs: how to compare subcategories?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, categorical-data, manova

I have continuous DVs and my IVs are two categorical variables, one is dichotomous (low/high) and one is multicategorical (1/2/3/4). I'm interested in comparing each group and their interactions. For instance I want to know how "1" compares to "3" and how "low" compares to "high", but also how "1 low" compares to "1 high". At first I went for a two-factors MANOVA on SPSS but that only compares the variables, not their levels. What would be the best analysis to get info on the subgroups? Thanks in advance!